# I need to create a new module to table exists with another prefix of mam

Tags: model, prefix, database-schema

I need to create a new module and this project have tables with other prefixes, How I omit this default prefix in my file /Model/ModelTable.php

this is the code inside:

```
namespace Arkix\Zonas\Model\Resource;

class Zona extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
     * @param string|null $resourcePrefix
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        $resourcePrefix = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $resourcePrefix);     
    }

    /**
     * Model Initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('app_places_zones', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: magento say this error:         2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mambo_dev2.mam_places_zones' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mam_places_zones` AS `main_table`
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mambo_dev2.mam_places_zones' doesn't exist

Comment: you need to create that table to your current DB schema or if you have an old database that is working export from there then import it to your current DB.

Comment: @andrwsv please explain what are you trying i din't get what you want to do. :)

Comment: @Himanshu This proyect have old tables created for other person and I need create one CRUD for that tables and that is my problem with prefix in the file model